# MongoDB - return document references as nested document

Tags: c#, mongodb, nested

imagine this structure:

collection companies:

```
{ 
  "company" : "foo",
  "city" : "1234"
}

{ 
  "company" : "bar",
  "city" : "1234"
}
```

collection cities:

```
{
  "_id" : "1234",
  "cityname" : "Berlin",
  "zipcode" : "09123"
}
```

now i want to get as result when i query for company = "foo":

```
{ 
  "company" : "foo",
  "city" : {
          "_id" : "1234",
          "cityname" : "Berlin",
          "zipcode" : "09123"
           }
}
```

How to query this from the C# driver? i have the result structure as C# class and i would like to have it strong-typed.

like this:

```
MongoCollection<Company> mc = mongodb.GetCollection<Company>("companies")
```

And the Class company looks like:

```
public class Company {
     public string company {get;set;}
     public City city {get;set;}
}
```

You should get the idea.
The Mongo ducomentation didn't say much about this.

Comment: Your question does not say much about why you would expect that result for "foo" and why it contains the value for "bar". Unless you explain clearly then you are not likely to get the answer you want.

Comment: I've extended the question and fixed the typo.

Comment: Still not sure what you are asking here. MongoDB does allow you to store "what you want" in a collection, but you seem to be using something like spring data, which of course will not. While it is possible to have really mixed data in a collection, it generally is not a good idea unless all you are really talking about is "polymorphic" associations. But parent/child in the same collection makes it hard for people to see your point. So possibly needs more "extension" or otherwise a re-think

Comment: just edited the question again. i would have the cities in an different collection than the companies. it's more about having an repetitive and equal nested document for multiple documents but storing it just once on the db and reference it internally on the db. but query it as it would be a nested one.

Comment: So basically you are looking for relational joins and yet have chosen MongoDB as your solution. Common reading on the web, "MongoDB does not do joins". You might want to think more about your next edit. You really need to explain yourself. Just trying to give some pointers here. MongoDB exists to fill a gap that relational SQL databases don't meet. Not a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Your are frequently asking the city data by reference, embedding this document makes it faster to query.

Restructure your document schema and embed the city (address) document into the company document.

```
{
    company : "Deutsche Bank",
    address : {
        street : "Müllerstraße",
        number : "34a",
        zipcode : "13353",
        city : "Berlin"
    }
}
```

If you have no other option because of any business logic is relying on the company document, you could choose to create aggregation queries and project a new document as result.

[additional info]
You have to run an extra query to get the referenced document, foreach every company and embed the city info.

Comment: The reason I am aiming on a change of the document schema is basically synergy and performance.

Comment: Getting back to a city level, i would have like 1000th's of companies with the same city document embedded. So i though i could save some space on the database by just having the city once in the db and referencing it internally but having the result as an embedded document.

Comment: That's why I have extended the city property to a address property to store more info into it then only a city name and zipcode. You have to solve this by using foreach on the cities.

Comment: The structure here is just an example. it's more about the general way how to do this sort of equal nested documents in mongo efficiently.

Comment: Although its just an example, a fine example with a typical relational approach to MongoDB. Like Neil is saying. There are no direct relationships within MongoDB, not like the ones in SQL. It's a complete different approach we would normally do with SQL. 

Just like MongoDB is describing in there documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Its better to embed a document into 1000 documents and solve this with just one query, like 

db.companies.find({ company : "foo" })